# CRM 2011 addCustomView to Partylist - Error when switching Entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

i´m trying to add a Custom View for contacts to a Partylist (Phonecall - field "to").
I add the view with

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('to').addCustomView(viewId, 'contact', viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, false);
```

It works very well, but if try to switch the Entity from contacts to another entity (for example accounts), I get following error:

> Entity Name specified in FetchXml does not match the entity name in the EntityExpression

This "bug" should be fixed since Update Rollup 10:

> The AddCustomView method from SDK does not work on a multi-entity lookup as expected. [CRM 2011 UR10](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2710577/en)

My system has Update Rollup 13.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: You can attempt to look at the minified javascript that is executed when you call AddCustomView and debug Microsoft's javascript.  Have fun with that one though...

Comment: did you verify that the entity you are switching to is an acceptable recipient for phone calls? (e.g. you cant make phone calls To the case/incident record).  Also you should check that the fetchXML and layoutXML are valid on the new entity.